# What is the difference between point of view and user story?

Tags: ux-designer

POV - [User . . . (descriptive)] needs [Need . . . (verb)] because [Insight . . . (compelling)]

User story - "As a , I want  so that "

and this sounds same to me. What's the difference?

Comment: Is "point of view" a construct in some methodology? Like in the same way a user story is part of agile frameworks?

Comment: Is this a question for Project Managers/Business Analysts? Doesn't look like a UX question to me.

Answer (score 2):

**User Stories** are used by software development teams and other stakeholders to **describe and communicate product features**.

**Point of View Statements** are used by designers employing the [Design Thinking methodology](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/5-stages-in-the-design-thinking-process), to **guide  the ideation process**.

---

Detailed Answer:

**1. User Stories**

**What are they?**
User Stories are short, simple descriptions of features, told from the perspective of the person who wants the feature.

They are not meant to be comprehensive feature specifications, but rather quick placeholders.

**Who uses them?**
User Stories are used by software development teams and product managers,

**In what context?**
They are most often used by those applying the *Agile / Scrum* methodology.

**Why are they useful?**
User Stories are used to facilitate understanding, communication and collaboration, both within the development team, and among wider stakeholders. They are also helpful for developers when providing estimates for features.

**2. Point of View Statements**

**What are they?**
Point of View statements are succinct, meaningful, actionable problem definitions that focus on specific users, their needs and relevant insights you have uncovered about them.

**Who uses them?**
POV statements are used by any UX or design practitioners applying the *Design Thinking* methodology.

**In what context?**

They are created during Stage 2 of the Design Thinking process -- the "*Define the Problem*" phase.

**Why are they useful?**
POV statements are used to define a problem in a way that facilitates and guides ideation, ensuring the right problem is addressed. The problem is defined from the user's perspective, capturing the needs and key insights about the user learned during the previous stage: "*Empathy*".

When the problem is defined correctly, the designers can begin to address the problem in the next stage: *Ideation*.

---

Notes:

The Interaction Design Foundation has a good example of how and why to write a POV statement: https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/define-and-frame-your-design-challenge-by-creating-your-point-of-view-and-ask-how-might-we

While Wikipedia has as good an good overview on User Stories as any: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/User_story

Answer (score 1):

I've never come across POV as a methodology. However from your brief description they are the same in content. It's probably just the same method (for very much alike) under a different name. For example, User Stories and Use Cases are very similar. However there are subtle differences.

[This article](https://www.stellman-greene.com/2009/05/03/requirements-101-user-stories-vs-use-cases/) describes and explains the differences between user stories and use cases. That might help you in figuring out where POV stands in all this.

Answer (score 0):

Point of view describes how  certain aspect is seen at  particular point. while  user experience/story is the effect of a particular circumstance. An experience of something.